# how to send a json object from index.js to html in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, d3.js

I'm getting a json data in index.js(node.js)by calling a RESTFUL Webservice

```
index.js:
===========
    var options = {
        host: '192.168.7.54',
        port:8080,
        path:'/restful/traffic/upload',
        method:'POST',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');


        res.on('data', function(d) {
            dbdata = [d];
            console.log(dbdata);
        });
    });
```

Here dbdata is the json object returned from webservice.Here,I want to redirect this dbdata into another html file(contains d3 pie chart) and use this dbdata in order to display pie chart.How can I go ahead now.Can anyone please give suggestions on this issue...

Comment: plz suggest me on this issue

Comment: Instead of getting data from RESTAPI to nodejs server then sending to data to client side, why not simply use ajax client side ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expressJS then you have to pass it while rendering the template.
If not then you will have to construct complete HTML here and pass it in res.end();